# Hi, what is a more pythonic way to set a value in python to any index in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I am creating my own data structure in python which I call an Array. One property that I would like it to have is if for instance `array = [1,2]`, one could write `array[5] = 6` and then `array = [1,2,None,None,None,6]`. I have accomplished this, but my code seems very awkward.

```
def __setitem__(self,index,value):
    try:
        self.array[index] = value
    except IndexError:
        if index+1 > len(self):
            add = index + 1 - len(self)
            self.array += [None] * add
            self.array[i] = value
```

Comment: you don't need the `try ... except` ... a simple `if` should do.

Comment: List comprehensions shouldn't be implemented for its side effects, but one can also have the same results doing: `[arr.append(None) for i in range(index-len(arr))]` and then `arr.append(value)`.

Comment: FYI, python has an array data type: https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html

Comment: @Alexander But what does that have to do with this?

Answer (score 10):

```
def __setitem__(self, index, value):
    self.array += [None] * (index + 1 - len(self.array))
    self.array[index] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks quite ok to me. If setting an element outside the existing range is an exception, using try-except here is the correct way. You should also consider the case, where `index` is not larger than length of the list.

```
from itertools import repeat

def __setitem__(self,index,value):
    try:
        self.array[index] = value
    except IndexError:
        if index < 0:
            raise
        self.array.extend(repeat(None, index-len(self)))
        self.array.append(value)
```